# RestTemplate returns null

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am trying to get information from a webservice by using RestTemplete. When I use the url on browser it returns:

```
   {
      "id": 4242,
      "node_id": "dsgs",
      "name": "keyboard",
      "full_name": "gsdfgs",
      "private": false,
      "owner": 
      {
        "login": "cdss",  
        "gravatar_id": "",

      },

      "description": " fdsfa",
      "fork": false
   }
```

The thing is I do not want to get all those information therefore I created a class with only few fields

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServiceInfo{

    @JsonProperty("node_id")
    private int nodeId;

    @JsonProperty("full_name")
    private String fullName;

    private String description;

    //setter getters
}
```

And I am calling the service as

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 ServiceInfo serviceInfo= restTemplate.getForObject(fullServiceUrl, ServiceInfo.class);
```

Here serviceInfo object is null there is no exception in log. What is the problem here ? Do I need to include all the fields that service is returning in my class ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I was trying to call by http instead of https.